# Implementing additional constraints in R's nnls

Tags: r, least-squares, minimization

I am using the [R interface to the Lawson-Hanson NNLS](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=nnls:nnls) implementation of an algorithm for non-negative linear least squares that solves `||A x - b||^2` with the constraint that all elements of vector x ≥ 0. This works fine but I would like to add further constrains. Of interest to me are:

1. Also minimize "energy" of x:
   `||A x - b||^2 + m*||x||^2`
2. Minimize "energy in the x derivative"
   `||A x - b||^2 + m ||H x||^2`, where H is the sum of identity and a matrix with -1 on the first off-diagonal
3. Most generally, minimize `||A x - b||^2 + m ||H x - f||^2`.

Is there are a way to coax nnls to do this by some clever way of restating the problems 1.-3. Above? The reason I have hope for such a thing is that there is a little-throw away comment in a paper by [Whitall et al](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022236489900115) (sorry for the paywall) that claims that "fortunately, NNLS can be adopted from the original form above to accommodate something in problem 3".

Comment: Does solution below work though, because I thought that nnls requires that all elements of the design matrix are positive, which for this A* matrix wouldn't be the case... It would work for solving case 1 above though. Maybe using quadprog instead of nnls would work though, as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136563/linear-regression-with-individual-constraints-in-r/415171#415171 for case 2? Case 1 is known as ridge regression, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205/how-to-derive-the-ridge-regression-solution, and case 2 as "fused ridge".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it m is a scalar, right? Consider the simple case m=1; you can generalize for other values of m by letting H* = sqrt(m) H   and f* = sqrt(m) f    and using the solution method given here.

So now you're trying to minimise ||A x - b||^2 + ||H x - f||^2.

Let A* = [A' | H']'   and let b* = [b' | f']'  (i.e. stack up A on top of H and b on top of f) and solve the original problem of
non-negative linear least squares on ||A* x - b*||^2 with the constraint that all elements of vector x ≥ 0 .

Comment: Yes, m is scalar. Oh dear - Slightly embarrassed - this was quite obvious and I had somehow confused myself with dimensions of the matrices and vectors involved. I've put that into my call to nnls and it works quite nicely...

Comment: Does this work though, because I thought that nnls requires that all elements of the design matrix are positive, which for this A* matrix wouldn't be the case... It would work for solving case 1 above though. Maybe using quadprog instead of nnls would work though, as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136563/linear-regression-with-individual-constraints-in-r/415171#415171 for case 2? Case 1 is known as ridge regression, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205/how-to-derive-the-ridge-regression-solution, and case 2 as "fused ridge".